# AngularJs - ng-route not work with top position

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I would like to create an animation when the page changes.

I had in mind an animation from bottom to top, the first loading animation works correctly, but if you go down the page and click on the link to change the page no longer works.

This problem is due to the fact that once shook the angular page no longer considers the top of the window but considers scroll the page.

I tried with date-autoscroll = "false", the page is repositioned well but you lose the animation.

Some idea?

`**DEMO**` http://plnkr.co/edit/j7r3s33Y3GcTyH2Fop9K?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add this in the main controller:

```
// RESET NG-VIEW TOP POSITION
  $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
```